# Tailwindcss 2.0 with SASS - use advanced selectors

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-8, laravel-mix, tailwind-css

how to write advanced selectors for tailwind (I'm using it in Laravel). I have e.g. this:

```
.nav-link {
    @apply px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium
    &-active {
        @apply bg-gray-900 text-white
    }
    &-inactive {
        @apply text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white
    }
}
```

But mix always fail with **Error: no parent could be found.**
If I use following format, it works, but I'm loosing the nice about Sass's advanced selectors:

```
.nav-link-active {
    @apply bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium
}
.nav-link-inactive {
    @apply text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your css inside a @layer in your `app.css` file? From their site, you should have something like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  .nav-link-active {
    @apply bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium;
  }
  .nav-link-inactive {
    @apply text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - you can't nest css *and* use @apply.

Per the docs, most of what you're probably using Sass for is possibly with PostCSS. I used the `postcss-nested` plugin to get nesting & apply working together.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting